# How to draw a dotted circle in easel js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

How to draw a dotted circle in easel js? I wants to create a circle , outer line should be in dotted format.How to solve this?

**Output:**

please refer this link: 
http://www.polyvore.com/dotted_circle/thing?id=75092766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circle creation in dotted style

```
        var graphics = new createjs.Graphics();
        CIRCLE_PAGE = new createjs.Container();
        var shape = new createjs.Shape(graphics);
        var total_circles = 4;
        var diameter = 200;
        var angle = i * 2 * Math.PI/total_circles;
        var x = cx + Math.cos(angle) * diameter/2;
        var y = cy + Math.sin(angle) * diameter/2;   
        shape.graphics.beginFill("#666666");
        shape.graphics.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        shape.graphics.closePath();
        CIRCLE_PAGE.addChild(shape);
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the "Graphics_setStrokeDash.html" example in GitHub. Here is a link to the source.
https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/Graphics_setStrokeDash.html

Note that it will not work in earlier IE versions (<11).

Snippet:

```
shape.graphics.setStrokeDash([2,2]);
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("green").rect(380,20,100,100);
```